# How change database in SQL Server manually and update model (classes) in code-first model in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, code-first

I created a database by my classes in code-first model of Entity Framework. I am using the migrations for updating database from my model classes.

Now how do change database and update my classes?

Comment: If you are using Code First and you are thinking about touching the database then you are going against the Code First principle. Code First works really well but you should not alter it's flow of development because things can get really really tricky. Consider sticking with Code First or other EF alternatives like Data Base First or Model First.

Comment: @Felipe Correa, This means that if I want to change my database shoud i switch from codefirst to db first?

Comment: You should never change between those EF approaches. You pick one and you should stick with it if you don't want any problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if i understand correctly but it seems that you should read more about EF migrations. You should never mix CodeFirst and DatabaseFirst approach.

If you are already using EF Migrations you should be aware of the multiple commands that you can run from the Package Manager Console, e.g. **Enable-Migrations**.

To migrate, you basically use the **Update-Database** command.

Read more aboput the topic here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx